# D3 sort() with CSV data

Tags: sorting, csv, d3.js

I am trying all kinds of ways to make `.sort()` work on my csv dataset. No luck.

I'd just like to sort my data by a "value" column.

This is the function I'm running inside my `d3.csv` api call and before I select the dom and append my divs:

```
dataset = dataset.sort(function (a,b) {return d3.ascending(a.value, b.value); });
```

Before I get to the `.sort`, I clean the data:

```
dataset.forEach(function(d) {
            d.funded_month = parseDate(d.funded_month);
            d.value = +d.value;
        });
    };
```

Everything seems in order. When I `console.log(d3.ascending(a.value, b.value))`, I get the right outputs:

```
-1 d32.html:138
1 d32.html:138
-1 d32.html:138
1 d32.html:138
etc..
```

Yet the bars data doesn't sort.

Comment: When are you rendering the graphic? Provide a plunkr or fiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not clear from the provided code but I will hazard a guess you are not handling async nature of d3.csv.

[This plunkr shows your sort code working fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/z8WdSry2349xassr2mtj). Note where the `data` object is declared, populated, and used.

here is a partial listing. I have added buttons that re-order `data`. To achieve this we need to put the ordering logic inside `render` rather than inside the `d3.csv` callback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var data = [];
d3.csv("data.csv",
        function(error, rows) {
            rows.forEach(function(r) {
                data.push({
                    expense: +r.expense,
                    category: r.category
                })
            });
            render();
        });

function render(d3Comparator) {
    if(d3Comparator) data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3[d3Comparator](a.expense, b.expense);
    });
    d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <-B
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("div")
            .attr("class", "h-bar")
            .append("span");
    d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <-C
            .data(data)
            .exit().remove();
    d3.select("body").selectAll("div.h-bar") // <-D
            .style("width", function(d) {
                return (d.expense * 5) + "px";
            })
            .select("span")
            .text(function(d) {
                return d.category;
            });
}

</script>

<button onclick="render('ascending')">Sort ascending!</button>
<button onclick="render('descending')">Sort descending!</button>
```

Comment: Many thanks for this. I noticed you used the double csv(), function(), function().

Originally, I used this as well. Why is it preferred to just having a single function and extrapolating your d.xyz values from the dataset?

Comment: There is no real advantage. It is just for convenience. Always lots of ways to do the same thing. I think you will usually want a separate `render` function with access to `data` because you will often want to dynamically re-order or re-calculate `data`.

Comment: I'm leaving my csv() function in my parent scope function, then drawchart() and updatechart() inside that function. But yes..