# d3 find first entry of data category

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm making a d3 chart where I attempt to do the following:
I have different categories and I want to show the category label only when it appears for the first time (since I sort by category anyhow).
I've tried this:

```
    d.isFirstInstanceOfCategory = (i === 0 || d.Kategorie !== data[i-1].Kategorie);
```

but this is only checking if the preceding data entry is the same as the current one. However what I need to check is if it is the first of all preceeding entries.
Can someone help?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment yet so will update my answer if need more information. If it's already sorted, then shouldn't it be the first of all preceeding entries. If not sorted, then you could create another array based on number of category items and flag the category when first appears.

```
d.isFirstInstanceOfCategory = (i === 0 || d.Kategorie !== data[i-1].Kategorie && d.Kategorie.NotAlreadyFlagged)
```

Below are some options for sorting but looks like you have that covered already.

1) [Sortable Bar Chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3885705)

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
        .sort(function(a, b) { return x0(a.letter) - x0(b.letter); });
```

2) [D3 sort() with CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100680/d3-sort-with-csv-data)

```
function render(d3Comparator) {
    if(d3Comparator) data = data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return d3[d3Comparator](a.expense, b.expense);
    });
<button onclick="render('ascending')">Sort ascending!</button>
<button onclick="render('descending')">Sort descending!</button>
```